# Saving jpeg depth image from /camera/depth/image on Kinect

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, image-view, depth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello. When I try right clicking the image window, from image:=/camera/depth/image,
to save the image on jpeg format I get on my folder a totally black picture. I know it works on RGB images and on image:=/camera/depth/image_rect_raw.
So any idea to get the image on jpeg format from image:=/camera/depth/image cuz it's way better than image:=/camera/depth/image_rect_raw.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42017/saving-jpeg-depth-image-from-/camera/depth/image-on-kinect/) by [Fer Nunez](https://answers.ros.org/users/2960/fer-nunez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Neither of those is an *image* in the JPEG sense. They are *depth* images.

If you want the RGB camera image, use [one of these topics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch#Published_Topics) (or the rectified versions):

- camera/rgb/image_mono
- camera/rgb/image_color

See [REP-0118](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0118.html) for details.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can get a depth image suscribing to the ROS topic and using OpenCV to save the file

```
    void kinectWindow::getDepthImageFromKinect(sensor_msgs::Image image)
{    
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr(new cv_bridge::CvImage);
     
    if (frameCounter==6) {
    char numstr[21]; // enough to hold all numbers up to 64-bits
    sprintf(numstr, "%d", fileCounter);
    std::string result = directory + name + numstr + ext;
    
    cv::imwrite(result, (cv_ptr->image)*10);
    frameCounter = 0;
    fileCounter++;
    } else {
    frameCounter++;
    }
}
```

Just initializate as string directory, name (filename), and desired extension (ext)  and  be sure to suscribe to the right topic... You can check how to suscribe to topics [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers)

---

Originally posted by [Luis Parra](https://answers.ros.org/users/2689/luis-parra/) with karma: 11 on 2012-09-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1